# How to convert a class object into a string

Tags: php

I have this of code but when I run it, it says object can not be converted to string.

```
    $db = Database::getDB();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch();
    $category = CategoryDB::getCategory($row['categoryID']);
    $fileName = new Product($category, $row['productCode']);


    $dir = "../images/";
    unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic method [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

```
class Product
{
    public $fileName;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }
}
```

Whenever you treat the object like a string (e.g print it out), this method will handle it. The resulting string will be whatever this method returns.

That said, having a Product object convert to a filename string doesn't seem logically sound. Maybe you would prefer a `getFilename()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are writting:

```
$fileName = new Product($category, $row['productCode']);
```

And later you are doing:

```
unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName);
```

As you can see you are trying to use the object $filename as a string.
This cannot be done, or at least it is not a good practice (Magic __toString()). You need to check the Object Product for a method that can allow
you to extract the file name.

Eg:

```
unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName->getFileName());
```